# Idioms, how do they work?

Tags: idioms

So, my friend and I were chatting the other day. I, being a new father, sent him a picture of my clothesline completely full of my daughter's diapers. Then this dialogue happened:

> My friend: Woah, babies are really poop factories.
>   Me: No shit.

Now, at that point, the chat spiraled out to a discussion on how wrong I was on using *no shit* on *poop factory*. Words such as *"complete opposite"* and *"idioms, idiot"* were uttered. I pointed my friend at the definition at [thefreedictionary.com definition](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/no+shit):

> *no shit* (rude)
>
> 1. something is very surprising and hard to believe *He's coming here tonight? No shit!*
> 2. the truth *This is no shit - we're going to have the money for you tomorrow.*

He wouldn't have it. So, I turn to ELU as final arbiter. Was my response above correct or not?

Edit: After accepting the answer below, I notice that this question could use a better title. If you have a better idea on what should this question be titled, please edit it and remove this paragraph.

Comment: It works on a number of levels. As sarcasm, as proof of the cleanliness of the diapers in the picture, as irony... your friend is humorless.

Comment: Yes, very witty. Clever extension of the metaphor. Definitely got a chuckle out of me.

Comment: "When established idiom clashes with grammar, correctness is on the side of the idiom. Put another way, if sticking grimly to rules of grammar makes you sound like a pompous pedant, you are a pompous pedant." William Safire (1983) 



Not directly applicable to your scenario but you could easily substitute "logic" for "grammar".

Comment: @medica, my friend's sense of humor is actually about the same level as mine, which is why a) he's my friend, and b) the discussion went on for so long.

Comment: Ah! My apologies. You are both humorless!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Correct and appropriate.

Additionally *No shit Sherlock* ==> "You are stating the obvious"

which according to [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/no_shit,_Sherlock) breaks down into

> **no shit** (“an expression of amazement”) + **Sherlock** (“a fictional detective who makes ingenious deductions”)

Comment: I'll accept this one. I originally wanted to add the Sherlock, but he wasn't much of a Sherlock :p

Answer (score 1):

As was already mentioned, *no shit* does in fact mean *yes, exactly*.

What is even better it's how you successfully managed to have the words *no shit* actually mean *yes, a lot of shit*. Whether you intended such a clever play on words or not you are indeed correct. I shit you not.

Answer (score 0):

Mplungjan has explained one sense in which your response was appropriate.

There is another too, though it does involve inserting a comma into your original formulation:

> *"No, shit".*

Or perhaps (even more appropriately, given the topic) a colon:

> *"No: shit".*

You would say this if you felt that *shit* was a more suitable word than *poop* to describe your child's excreta (for instance, because you are the type of person who believes in calling a spade a spade rather than a 'digging implement'). It also puns rather pleasingly on the idiom that Mplungjan described.