# Is there a word for the act of butchering a language for the sake of a joke?

Tags: single-word-requests, idioms, phrase-requests

My friend and I (may or may not be the same one from [my other question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/197625)) were chatting the other day and we came to a discussion about the idiom [*tit-for-tat*](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/tit-for-tat).

> **tit-for-tat** (*informal*)
> a tit-for-tat action is something bad that you do to someone because they have done something bad to you (always before noun) *Six of the victims died in tit-for-tat attacks.* (*informal*)

In the middle of said discussion, my friend suddenly swerved into a discussion about his new business idea.

> **tat-for-tit** (*business model*)
> I'll ink some stuff on you for boob pics.

Don't worry, I've given him several pieces of my mind on why that business model won't work (such as *pics don't pay bills* and *you can't draw anything to save your life*). My actual question is:

> Is there a word/phrase for either:
>
> - an act of butchering a language for the sake of a joke
>
> and/or
>
> - a person who does said act

Comment: I was about to suggest pun, but someone beat me to it :) FYI, TFD is actually very good. Your friend didn't "butcher" the language, he merely swapped a *tit* with a *tat*, a play on words.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you may be referring to a [pun](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Pun):

> - play on words, sometimes on different senses of the same word and sometimes on the similar sense or sound of different words.
> - (Literary & Literary Critical Terms) the use of words or phrases to exploit ambiguities and innuendoes in their meaning, usually for humorous effect; a play on words. An example is: "Ben Battle was a soldier bold, And used to war's alarms: But a cannonball took off his legs, So he laid down his arms." (Thomas Hood)

Source: www.thefreedictionary.com

Comment: Yeah, I suppose "a really bad pun" or "how droll" ... I don't think there's a term for "achingly bad pun" is there?

Comment: @JoeBlow For an _achingly bad pun_, should I offer a _PUNgent pun_?

Comment: heh !  good one Story!

Answer (score 0):

People laugh because their defense mechanism is interrupted; if one eliminated all jokes that someone finds in poor taste, you'd wipe out 90% of them.

The general term for jokes that butcher the language is *humor* and the person performing such an act is a *comic*.

All puns butcher the language, but not all jokes which butcher the language are puns.

Comment: Puns don't necessarily butcher the language; some are very elegant and clever, and don't (as you imply) force the hearer to cringe. The same applies to jokes in general.

Answer (score -3):

I think the word you are looking for is: malapropism (also called a Dogberryism).

For some really great ones, Google Yogi Berra's malaprops.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. It would be better if you can post any reference/research/link that can support your answer. You are the one who should post examples when posting an answer. I would advise you to take the [tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit our [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) to see how it works here.